# Manipulation with list

Tags: prolog

I am trying to understand prolog through examples. I wrote a piece of code but it is not working in desired manner and I am unable to find the fault.

```
list([]).


test([],_,_).                   
test([Child|List],B,C) :-
   append([Child],B,C),
   test(List,B,C).  

testme :-
        list(Final),
        test([1,2,3],Final,Result),
        write(Result).
```

The functionality which I require from this code that the `Result` should be the reverse of input list. When I trace this code I found the reverse of input list in `C` but it is not returned.

I knows using `reverse` function I can easily find reverse of list but my interest is not in finding the reverse but to understand this code and working of prolog. So please can someone tell me where I am wrong and what modification is required in this code to work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let's see why your code does not work.

```
test([],_,_).                   
test([Child|List],B,C) :-
   append([Child],B,C),
   test(List,B,C).
```

You tried to define a recursive predicate with two clauses.
The arguments to this predicate are: the input list (1), an intermediate list  (2) and the final result(3).

Your first clause is thus, wrong. 
Suppose your input list is just an empty list. The result should be an empty list. But in your first clause you are leaving the third argument as-is. Either it was already bound to somenthing (not useful in this case) or it was unbounded and therefore it will keep that way.

The second clause deals with recursion. It takes the first element of your input list, append it in the front of the intermediate list yielding another intermediate list.
Now you do the recursion step calling test again. But note that now the three arguments are instantiated! so you won't be able to append another item to the final list.

Here goes your test/3 predicate modified to work as you expect:

```
test([],List,List).
test([Child|List],B,D) :-
   append([Child],B,C),
   test(List,C,D).
```

Now the first clause just unifies the second and third argument.
So in our first test case (empty input list), recall that the second argument was also an empty list, so the third argument will also be an empty list => correct.

Now for the recursive clause.
It will take the first element of the input list and append it to the intermediate list, and unify it on a fresh variable.
Now we go into the recursion step, but now we use that list (C) as the intermediate list.
This, on recursion, will build the output list, now bound to D which is what we use as output.

As you are just appending one element to the intermediate list each time, you could have got rid of the append with something like:

```
test([],List,List).
test([Child|List],B,C) :-
   test(List,[Child|B],C).
```

Comment: thank you very much for such a descriptive answer. It helps a lot. :)

Answer (score 0):

Prolog rules can only "return" values (since there is really no distinction between parameters and return values) by unifying them with their arguments.  Assuming you want an accumulator-based `reverse` operation, you will need three parameters to `test`, and it should act as if it was written as:

```
test(A, B, C) :- reverse(A, A2), append(A2, B, C).
```

Having an implicit append operation in `test` will make the recursion easier to write.  Also, note that you can write `append([A], B, C)` as `C = [A | B]` (or replace `C` by `[A | B]`).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions but I want to use recursion also. I am not interested in result but it should work properly I want to know reasons behind its faulty run. I tried to modify my code but it is also not working. I have updated my code in question section